# How to perform sigma clipping on data set?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

*Context: I am looking at the change of velocity of an object periodically, where the period is 1.846834days and I am expecting a sinusoidal fit to my set of data.
Suppose I have a set of data which look like this:

```
#days        vel         error
5725.782701 0.195802    0.036312
5729.755560 -0.006370   0.041495
5730.765352 -0.071253   0.030760
5745.710214 0.092082    0.036094
5745.932853  0.238030   0.040097
5749.705307 0.196649    0.037140
5741.682112 0.186664    0.028075
5742.681765 -0.262104   0.038049
6186.729146 -0.243796   0.031687
6187.742803 -0.009394   0.054541
6190.717317 -0.001821   0.033684
6192.716356 0.117557    0.037807
6196.704736 0.093935    0.032336
6203.683879 0.076051    0.033085
6204.679898 -0.301463   0.033483
6208.659585 -0.409340   0.036002
6209.669701 0.180807    0.041666
```

There are only one or two data points observed in each cycle, so what I wanted to do is to phase fold my data, plot them and fit my data using chi-square minimization. This is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize as op
import csv

with open('testdata.dat') as fin:
  with open('testdata_out.dat', 'w') as fout:   #write output in a new .dat file
    o=csv.writer(fout)
    for line in fin:
        o.writerow(line.split())


#create a 2d array and give names to columns
data = np.genfromtxt('testdata_out.dat',delimiter=',',dtype=('f4,f4,f4'))
data.dtype.names = ('bjd','rv','err')


# parameters
x = data['bjd']

y = data['rv']

e = data['err']

P = 1.846834    #orbital period

T = 3763.85112  #time from ephemeris

q = (data['bjd']-T)%P

#print(q)


def niceplot():
    plt.xlabel('BJD')
    plt.ylabel('RV (km/s)')
    plt.tight_layout()

def model(q,A,V):
    return A*np.cos(np.multiply(np.divide((q),P),np.multiply(2,np.pi))-262) + V

def residuals((A,V),q,y,e):     #for least square
    return (y-model(q,A,V)) / e

def chisq((A,V),q,y,e):
    return ((residuals((A,V),q,y,e))**2).sum()

result_min = op.minimize(chisq, (0.3,0), args=(q,y,e))
print(result_min)


A,V = result_min.x
xf = np.arange(q.min(), q.max(), 0.1)
yf = model(xf,A,V)

print(xf)
print(yf)

plt.errorbar(q, y, e, fmt='ok')
plt.plot(xf,yf)
niceplot()
plt.show()
```

[image: Chi-squared minimized fit]

In my plot, the shape of the sine curve seems to fit my data, but it does not go through all the data points. 
My question is: How can I perform sigma clipping such that I can get a better fit for my set of data? I know the curve_fit module in Scipy may do the job. But I would like to know if it is possible to perform sigma clipping while using minimize module??

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: chi-square assumes  that your data are random samples from a fixed (normal) distribution. Hence, only 68% of the samples are within 1-sigma from the mean model/ best fit line. I think your best fit line is pretty close.